# ECS service discovery - how to implement ribbon or its equivalent

Tags: amazon-web-services, service-discovery

I am attempting to use ECS service discovery explained here

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/

I am able to get the instances registered as A records under service name in Route53. Now the next thing is to implement something equivalent to spring cloud ribbon which would hold a cache of the service registry.

I looked at examples that uses dig and jndi. But those methods makes call to R53 at the time of execution which could add to the latency.

Does anyone has any suggestions or better methods?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution